# Alternative to Android Studio

Tags: windows, android, software-development, ide

There is a paper on Android programming lab in my next semester. My old laptop (Windows 10 64 bit, 4GB) is not capable of running the Android Studio. Is there any lightweight alternative with similar functionalities?

Comment: I’m surprised it can’t cope, but I’d guess it’s the memory that’s a problem. Laptop memory is fairly cheap, and easy to fit if you have the right screwdrivers - look into an upgrade?

Comment: I have a Pentium processor (4th generation) only which was sufficient for other programming languages, until this one. Will adding an extra 4 GB help? Cannot upgrade laptop processor without discarding the entire laptop.

Comment: Oh OK - [the system requirements](https://developer.android.com/studio/#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa) do say 8GB of RAM, but they do also specify 2nd generation Intel Core or newer. I've lost track of Pentium vs Core so I'm not sure how that compares.

Answer (score 2):

Like most IDEs, Android Studio is a graphical shell which uses a lot of command line tools underneath. You can use a text editor of your choice, preferably with syntax highlighting (e.g. Notepad++) to edit Java/Kotlin/Gradle files in your project, and use the command line to compile and run your project. It might be challenging to run an Android emulator with so few resources, but you can always debug/test on a real device.

You can download the command line tools from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads) (you have to scroll down a bit to "Command line tools only").